# MongoDB Count on millions of row is very slow

Tags: c#, mongodb, performance, mongodb-query

Using MongoDB 2.4 with mongoDB .NET driver 3.2

I have a collection with 30 million entries.

```
var visits = new MongoHelper<CampaignVisitLog>()
         .GetCollection().AsQueryable().Count(t => t.campaignId == campaignId);
```

campaignId is indexed. 
Depending on many entries campaignId has it will take from 30 seconds to several minutes to return the count.

Whats the correct way to count this collection?

Comment: How fast is it if you query the mongo collection directly, without the driver?

Comment: Count with prediction in nosql is ugly. Try to update mongodb also I didn't see any update related with count performance but it may help.

Comment: @liam : the query in mongo collection directly is very slow as well I waited for a very long time. and finally when the result came I didnt even get a count. It just returned "true" (mongo studio management)

the query i ran was: db.campaignvisitlog.count({campaignid:5})

Comment: @ErkanDemirel what do you mean by "try to update mongodb"?

Comment: I meant to mongo db version to 3.2.

Comment: Please add a sample doc and the output of `db.yourColl.getIndices()`.

Comment: The shell command you list has a typo; be sure you're trying `db.campaignvisitlog.count({campaignId:5})` (capital I) in the shell.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a collection with 30 million entries.

Independently of optimizing the whole query, you can't think that you're going to get blazing-fast responses with millions of items.

If you're performing other queries to get stats, maybe it's the time to schedule this calculations and do them with some asynchronous service (i.e. *a Windows service*, *Windows scheduled task*, *Quartz.NET*...), and get their results also asynchronously.

You can either use MongoDB to store your calculation service results or go for a more specific solution: a *service bus* (i.e. *RabbitMQ*, *Azure Service Bus*, *NServiceBus*...).

Comment: I have the same data in MSSQL and its blazing fast to count from that table. Im just testing if mongoDb is a good option for storing large datasets with this kind of log data, but seems like its not?

Comment: @Joakim A count in SQL is optimised in a totally different way. Mongo isn't necessarily any faster than SQL, it's an unstructured data store of documents not a relational database. If you main reason for using mongo is *"becasue it's faster"* you may find you're disappointed. It *may* be faster it may not, it depends on what your doing with it and how you store you data. **TL;DR Mongo is not SQL but faster**

Comment: In my experience for financial you should stick but other than this mongo is fine espicially for logging. If you want sum,count stick with sql. But if you want db for loggin stick with nosql.

Comment: @Joakim BTW, even with SQL if your app gets millions requests you'll need to go with the approach I've suggested you already in my answer

Comment: A year later. Turns out mongoDb isnt even really good at just listing a small set of last inserted rows in a collection

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB C# driver is sick.

LINQ queries are always translated to aggregation framework pipelines.

```
var pipeline = [ { "$group" : { "_id" : 1, "__result" : { "$sum" : 1 } } }]
db.test.aggregate(pipeline)
```

This results in a full collection scan on the server because the LINQ query did not specify any constraints.

Answer (score 0):

ensure you have enough memory to store your index in ram.

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/ensure-indexes-fit-ram/

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer

Comment: See you said *ensure* and you just provide a link. This could be a comment, and later the OP could discuss with you if this is the issue or not.